# Celery: why is there a multi-second time gap from when a task is accepted and when it starts to execute?

Tags: python, django, performance, celery, django-celery

I have a celery task:

```
@app.task(bind=True, soft_time_limit=FreeSWITCHConstants.EXECUTE_ATTEMPTS_LOCAL_SOFT_TIME_LIMIT)
def execute_attempt_local(self, attempt_id, provider_id, **kwargs):
  print "PERF - entering execute_attempt_local"
  ...
```

that is processed by a (remote) worker with the following config:

```
celery -A mycompany.web.taskapp worker n -Q execute_attempts-2 --autoscale=4,60
```

This task gets spawned thousands at a time and has historically completed in 1-3s (it's a mostly I/O bound task).

Recently as our app's overall usage has increased, this task's completion time has increased to 5-8s on average and I'm trying to understand what's taking up the extra time. I noticed that for many tasks taking 5-8 seconds, ~4s is taken in the time in between the task being accepted by the thread and executing the first line of the task:

```
[2019-09-24 13:15:16,627: DEBUG/MainProcess] Task accepted: mycompany.ivr.freeswitch.tasks.execute_attempt_local[d7585570-e0c9-4bbf-b3b1-63c8c5cd88cc] pid:7086
...
[2019-09-24 13:15:22,180: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-60] PERF - entering execute_attempt_local
```

What is happening in that 4s? I'm assuming I have a Celery config issue and somewhere there is a lack of resources for these tasks to process quicker. Any ideas what could be slowing them down?

Comment: It may even be minutes, even hours - depending on the utilisation of your workers, right. If you send 10000 tasks, and you only have 10 available worker processes, who knows when the other 9990 tasks will start...

Comment: I think you mean threads, not workers right? If so you're saying celery is waiting here to hand off to a thread because no thread is available? Meaning if I increase autoscale should I see an improvement here?

Comment: You use prefork concurrency, so those are all simple processes. Our cluster uses that too and we run up to 5 million tasks per day...

Comment: Autoscaling is, believe it or not, deprecated feature of Celery, because nobody is interested in maintaining it. So I suggest you fix the concurrency `N * <number of cores>` because your tasks are IO-bound so you can have 2-3 times more worker processes then number of cores.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible reasons why is this happening. It may take some time for the autoscaler to kick-in. So depending on your load, you may not have enough worker-processes to run your tasks when they are sent, so they are waiting in the queue for some time (it can even be minutes or hours) until there are available worker-processes.

You can easily monitor this by looking how many tasks are waiting in the queue. If the queue is always empty that means your tasks are executed immediately. If not, that means you may want to add new workers to your cluster.

Comment: As mentioned, this worker faces thousands of tasks coming in at any given time. And since there are limited threads, there is almost always tasks in the queue (multiple thousands).

But that's not the concern here. I'm seeing a gap AFTER the task has been accepted. I'm assuming that means there is already a thread assigned to it. And yet there are few seconds gap for the thread to actually start executing it. My question is why that gap

Comment: Precisely - that is why you see delays.

Comment: I think you may be confusing task received and task accepted. Task received is the queue time. This is a gap after the task is accepted. So it's after thread has already begun executing

Comment: See... Each worker has N number of worker-processes it controls. It pre-fetches M tasks (you cannot disable prefetching), but if all its worker-processes are busy it may take some time to start tasks it received.

Comment: Again, I am not concerned about the minutes or hours BEFORE a task starts to execute. I'm concerned about the task execution time AFTER it starts to execute. Please see my question. Task completion times do not consider the time in the queue. It's the execution time. Earlier my tasks took 1-3s. Now they are taking 5-8s. That is not 4s of extra queue time. It is 4s extra of execution time